# How to express "this" reference to lambda which implement interface?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, this

I need to implement a listener to controller. And when some condition occurs the listener should be removed. The condition can be checked inside the listener so it can be removed on time.

Here is a raw implementation:

```
fooController
        .addListener(object : OnListener {
            override fun onChanged() {
                if (/* some condition which means that the listener is no longer needed*/) {
                    navController.removeListener(this)//how to replace?
                    return@OnListener
                }
                //do on chande regular code
            }
        })
```

but I needed to create object directly and inherent form interface OnListener. I cannot figure out how to use lambda expression here. Especially for "this" reference.

I tried to write:

```
   fooController
          .addListener {
                    if (/* some condition which means that the listener is no longer needed*/) {
                        navController.removeListener(this)//this refer to outer class
                        return@OnListener
                    }
                    //do on chande regular code
                }
            }
```

but here keyword "this" refer to outer class. I know that could be used a "@"-syntax but cannot figure out
what should be after "this". Nider find in docs.

Comment: This is a limitation of lambdas. You should continue using the anonymous object.